# c++ array default parameter, while making function overloaded

Tags: c++, arrays, default-parameters

Lauguage : C++

I have to make function 'add' overloaded.

'add' function has array a[] as parameter.

I wrote my code but it doesn't work.

There is no error or caution but it doesn't start.

What is the problem on my code?

```
int add(int a[], int n, int b[])
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        sum += (a[i] + b[i]);
    return sum;
}

int add(int a[], int n=5)
{
    return add(a, n, NULL);
}
```

Comment: "It doesn't start" is certainly an incorrect interpretation of events.

Comment: Does the assignment say that `a[]`  is an array parameter? That is misleading, because it really is a pointer. Arrays aren't pointers and it is good to understand that early on.

Comment: What do you think passing `NULL` does? Hint: it's not an array of zeroes.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare arguments like array in the way you do (e.g. `int a[]`) then the compiler actually declares the argument to be a pointer.

And in the three-argument overload of the `add` function the third argument (`b`) could be a null pointer which you don't check for. Attempting to dereference a null pointer leads to *undefined behavior* and a probable crash.

Don't access `b` if it's a null pointer.

---

```
int add(int* a, int n, int* b)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (b == nullptr)
            sum += a[i];
        else
            sum += a[i] + b[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Um.. you mean that I have to delete NULL in the

return add(a, n, NULL).

Then, how I can give value NULL or 0 value to b[] if there is no third parameter?

Comment: @HoSuk No, I mean you need to add an `if (b == nullptr)` check in the function.

Comment: `int add(int a[], int n, int b[])
{
 if (b == nullptr)
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
   b[i] = 0;
 int sum = 0;
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  sum += (a[i] + b[i]);
 return sum;
}`

Comment: Ah, `b[i] = 0;` is an error. Thanks to your modified code, now the program work properly. I really really appreciate your help. Maybe I have to study harder.

Answer (score 1):

```
sum += (a[i] + b[i]);
```

indexes `b`, which can be `NULL`. That's Undefined Behavior.

A good way to avoid that pitfall is to use `std::vector`.